# SwiftUI, remove space between views in a VStack?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Why is there so much space between the three blue rectangles and the list? How can I remove the space so that all views within the VStack stack at the top? I tried using a `Spacer()` directly after the List, but nothing changed.

[image: spacing]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() { UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Faux Title")
                            .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            // settings
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                                .font(.system(.title2))
                        })
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        HStack() {
                            Text("1")
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.30, height: 150)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("2")
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.30, height: 150)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("3")
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.30, height: 150)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    List {
                        Text("One")
                        Text("Two")
                        Text("Three")
                        Text("Four")
                        Text("Five")
                        Text("Six")
                    }
                    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Bonus question:** In web development, you can open your browser's Web Inspector and use the element selector to click on elements which highlights their borders. Useful for something like this where you're trying to figure out which element the offending spacing belongs to. Is there something like that in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that your HStack with the blue rectangles is going to be a height of `150`, you should constrain it to that using `.frame(height: 150)`:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ...
}
.padding()
.frame(height: 150) //Here
```

Otherwise, the `GeometryReader` will occupy all available vertical space.

Re: your web dev comparison, check out the Xcode view hierarchy inspector. It's not exactly the same, but it's in the same vein: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: Yes! This fixes it! Thank you. And your tip about the View Hierarchy is pure gold.

Answer (score 4):

```swift
VStack(spacing: 0) {...} 
Spacer()
```

to your question you can in Xcode use the view inspector. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. But thanks for the heads-up about the View Hierarchy!